# Question about the Jacobian of a function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, analytic-geometry

Let $f:U\rightarrow V$ , $U$ and $V$ open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$, be a smooth function. Let $Jf_p$ be the jacobian of $f$ in the point $p\in U$ and set $M_p:=\sup\{|df_pv|:\|v\|=1\}$ and $m_p:=\inf\{|df_pv|:\|v\|=1\}$. If fear I'm missing something quite basic, but I can't understand why is it true $Jf_p=M_pm_p$. Can you give some hints?

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like a problem in linear algebra, the fact that the matrix is the Jacobian doesn't matter.

Comment: This is just a linear algebra; for any two-by-two matrix $A$, $A$ is diagonalizable or conjugate to an upper triangular matrix of the same diagonal entries(think of Jordan decomp for example), and for each case $M$ and $m$ is the two diagonal entries which are multiplied to the determinant.

Comment: Yes, I too thought it was a question of linear algebra, but I can't understand how exactly. If I write the Jacobian of $f$ (the matrix, not the determinant) with respect to the basis $\{u,v\}$ ($u$ is the vector which realizes $Mf_p$ and $v$ is the vector which realizes $mf_p$) and the basis $\{\frac{df_pu}{|df_pu|},\frac{df_pv}{|df_pv|}\}$ then it is diagonal of the form $\begin{pmatrix} |df_pu|&0\\0&|df_pv|\end{pmatrix}$ but this matrix is not conjugate to the jacobian...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be an arbitrary $2\times 2$ matrix. It is well known that $A$ has a singular value decomposition $A = U D V$, where $U,V$ are orthogonal and $D = \rm{diag}(\sigma_1, \sigma_2)$ is a diagonal matrix with nonnegative entries and $\sigma_1 \geq \sigma_2$.

Now, since orthogonal matrices have determinant $\pm 1$, we get $|\det A| = \sigma_1 \sigma_2$.

But since $U,V$ preserve norms, we also have
$$
\sup_{|v|=1} |Av| =\sup |Dv| = \sigma_1.
$$
If you replace sup by inf, you get$\sigma_2$.

This easily yields the claim.

Comment: Does this argument imply that, in the notation of my previous comment, $u\perp v$ and $\frac{df_pu}{|df_pu|}\perp\frac{df_pv}{|df_pv|}$?